# How many distinct bags can be formed containing at least one bagel of each kind?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A bakery has $8$ kinds of bagels. A bag holds a dozen bagels. How many distinct bags can be formed containing at least one bagel of each kind?

**My Answer:** We start by choosing one bagel of each type. Then we have already selected 8 bagels, and need to add 4 more to complete the dozen. This corresponds to the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^{8}x_{i} = 4$$ which is $C_{7}^{11}=330$. Would anyone mind checking if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Verifying your answer...

---

The $4$ "duplicate" bagels can be chosen as follows:

- $1,1,1,1\implies4$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom84=70$ ways
- $1,1,2  \implies3$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom83=56$ ways
- $1,2,1  \implies3$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom83=56$ ways
- $2,1,1  \implies3$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom83=56$ ways
- $2,2    \implies2$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom82=28$ ways
- $1,3    \implies2$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom82=28$ ways
- $3,1    \implies2$ unique types, which can be chosen in $\binom82=28$ ways
- $4      \implies1$ unique type,  which can be chosen in $\binom81= 8$ ways

Yielding a total of $70+56+56+56+28+28+28+8=330$ distinct bags.